# Chart for Real time data with duplicate x axis

Tags: charts, google-visualization, chart.js, canvasjs, smoothie.js

I need a real time graph which has to be generated using the data from a text file. (Graph has to be like system usage chart). The data will be added to the text file from the server every second. This file contains numerous duplicate entries. (For example at no usage of CPU,the value will be zero). The x and y axis values are within a limit only (Say upto 20000). The problem with the charts libraries I have used is they doesnt plot the duplicate points or they plot on the same point.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code design and writing service. Please show us you attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the docs [here](https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/dynamic-live-line-chart/). There is a solution right there, working for you.